# Data Validation in C using while Loop

Tags: c, validation

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char status;
    printf("STATUS     SYMBOL\n");
    printf("------     ------\n");
    printf("Senior        s\n");
    printf("Junior        j\n");    
    while(1)
    {       
        printf("Please Enter the Salesperson's Status : ");
        scanf("%c",&status);
        if (status=='s' || status=='j')
        {
            if(status=='s')
            {
                printf("Weekly Salary is --- $400\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {   
                printf("Weekly Salary is --- $275\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please Enter a Valid Symbol!\n");

        }
    }
}
```

When an Invalid data is entered,this program must ask user for a valid data.The While Loop used for validating the Data executing Two times,in order to ask the user for Input. Why the scanf function is being ignored on the First-Go? How to solve this Problem?  [Program Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN5U4.png)

Comment: `scanf("%c",&status);` ==> `scanf(" %c",&status);` note the added space.

Comment: Use `" %c"` so you skip over whitespace before the status character.

Comment: The second call is reading the newline after the character.

Comment: **Always** check the result of `scanf` and other functions which can encounter error conditions relevant for program execution.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you type `a<ENTER>` you type 2 characters.
So the first scanf get the `a`, the second one gets the `\n` (ENTER).

You can change your scanf to get 2 characters instead of one.

```
scanf("%c%c", &status, &newline);
```

Comment: Or even `scanf("%c%*c", &status);`